# How can I retrieve a binary based image from mssql(database) using php PDO?

Tags: php, database, pdo

```
<?php
    $sql = utf8_decode("SELECT Photo,Code_Musicien FROM Musicien WHERE Code_Musicien=?");

    try {
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(array($_GET['image']));
      $stmt->bindColumn(1, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database." . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    if (is_string($lob)) {
       $lob = fopen('data://image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($lob), 'r');
    }

fpassthru($lob);
```

?>

Comment: Well, I actually print this in an img tag in another php page

Comment: So, you don't define it?  I don't see a definition in the above.  Also, code is of little help in a comment.

Comment: How should I define it?

Comment: The same way you define any other variable?  I don't know what you intend to do here with your code, so that's all I can offer at this time.

Comment: What I want to do is converting binary numbers to image from database and I almost got this code from manual php website and I just add the if condition for checking ($lob) whether is a string or not